# What is the correct way to attach two grounding sources to my electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding

I replaced my existing electrical panel with [this electrical panel](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-100-Amp-24-Space-48-Circuit-Indoor-Main-Breaker-Plug-On-Neutral-Load-Center-with-Cover-Value-Pack-HOM2448M100PCVP/204836362) in order to have more available slots to redo my kitchen. I have one 6# copper wire ran & attached the water main and one 6# copper ran outside & attached to two grounding rods. What is the correct way to attach these two grounding sources to my panel? (If it matters, I'm in Minnesota, USA.)

[image: photo of electrical panel]

Comment: Is this a main panel or a sub panel fed by the main?

Comment: Note that your water main is not a ground source (or at least it isn't in the UK).  Drinking water itself is a relatively poor conductor, and although the pipework may be metal, it can be replaced at any time with plastic!  (This doesn't mean that you shouldn't connect your water main to ground though.  You absolutely should.)

Comment: @EdBeal this is the main panel

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks Martin. I think this was the reason behind my inspector requesting the addition of external grounding rods.

Comment: Can you post a better shot of the overall setup of the panel? Right now, I can't tell if you've fitted any ground bars already or not...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I haven't, I believe the panel in question, as it is a main panel, has a shared neutral/grounding bar. If this response doesn't answer your question I can post a better photo tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is the main panel your neutrals and grounds can be on the same buss, there are usually several larger holes in the buss #6 copper is all that is required for driven rods and #4 for a ufer ground. On most panels the grounding and grounded busses can handle #14 thru #6  al9cu so back one of the screws off slip the wire in the hole and torque it appropriately, your panel has the torque values on the label. Make sure the bonding screw (usually green) is installed,  this ties both busses together and is the only place to tie them together. In the US all piping that may become energized is to be bonded to the system including gas pipes, water pipes can still be used as a ground electrode if in contact with earth for 10’ but this practice is not used as often today since most plumbing is plastic. So just pick a hole on either side and that’s all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt, don't be bashful about adding an accessory grounding bar or two. This attaches direct to the chassis of the panel.

This can be a wiring convenience, because you can terminate each of the cable's grounds at the grounding bar, rather than taking it all the way to the breaker with the neutral.

Separating the grounding bar from the neutral bar also aids making this panel a subpanel in the future; 24-space is worryingly small for a whole house, so that may be an option if/when you outgrow it.   The reason you can't just turn it into a 48-space using "double-stuff" breakers is that as of NEC 2017, most circuits must be AFCI or GFCI, and as of NEC 2020, virtually every circuit must be.  AFCI breakers are not possible in double-stuff, so every 120V circuit will need a full space, and every 240V circuit will need 2.   You might be grandfathered in that respect *today*, but if you do any renovation you'll quickly find yourself out of spaces.  *Again.*

I am also a big fan of 100% separate neutral and grounding bars, with a clear neutral-ground bond **that is a wire**.  That lets me clamp an ammeter around it to look for ground-fault leakage.

---

To the extent able, you should leave hots and neutrals long enough to reach every breaker space thay can. That will allow you to a) upgrade the circuit to AFCI or GFCI, since they need neutral at the breaker; and b) move the breakers around as needed to acommodate many things which need to be in a particular place - whole house surge suppressors, gen interlocks, solar power breakers etc.

Comment: This is a great answer with lots of insight but another answer more directly answered the question as asked. Thanks! I'll definitely consider adding a separate grounding bar. I'm a bit too far along in the project to upgrade the panel size but will look at adding a subpanel in the near future.

Comment: @Kirk nothing wrong with subpanels.  The only bad thing is running out of spaces and the ugly compromises which follow.